# Return 2d array from 3d array masked by 2d array

Tags: matlab

With a 3 dimensional matrix and 2 dimensional boolean mask, I am trying to return all the 3-value sets that correspond to a True in the mask. For example
I have the matrix:

```
matrix(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


matrix(:,:,2) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


matrix(:,:,3) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

and a mask:

```
mask =


   0   0   0
   0   1   1
   1   1   1

>> matrix(mask)

ans =

     7
     5
     8
     6
     9
```

this indexing seems to only mask the first slice of the 3d matrix. What can I do to return a 2d array with all the specified 3-value pairs?

Though the shape and order are not important, I would like my output to look something like the following, where one dimension of the output corresponds to 3rd dimension of the 3d array.

```
[7,7,7]
[5,5,5]
[8,8,8]
[6,6,6]
[9,9,9]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by turning the original 3d array into 2d where each row comes from a vector in the 3rd dimension:

```
matrix2 = reshape(matrix, [], size(matrix, 3))
matrix2 =

   1   1   1
   4   4   4
   7   7   7
   2   2   2
   5   5   5
   8   8   8
   3   3   3
   6   6   6
   9   9   9
```

Then use the indices of the 1's in `mask` as row indices:

```
vectors = matrix2(find(mask), :)
vectors =

   7   7   7
   5   5   5
   8   8   8
   6   6   6
   9   9   9
```

---

As [@LuisMendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) mentions in the comments, if `mask` is a logical array, you don't even need the call to `find`:

```
vectors = matrix2(mask, :)
vectors =

   7   7   7
   5   5   5
   8   8   8
   6   6   6
   9   9   9
```

Comment: `find` can be removed (assuming `mask` is `logical`)